# Sendmail account for sending e-mail on Ubuntu

Tags: smtp

I've got a clean installation of Ubuntu with Webmin running Sendmail.
I've got a domain mail.my-domain.com pointing at that server.

I want to make a SMTP account for sending out e-mails, such as account-name@my-domain.com.

How do I do this?

For the record, I've tried a lot of Google searching etc. but no tutorial, documentation etc. that I could find showed a simple step-by-step to this simple setup :(

Comment: Make a note that if you're going to send emails from your system, you have to make sure you're not on a residential IP address.  Most ISPs will block email sending from your systems on residential-class networks (sending with an SMTP server, not via gmail or an external SMTP)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to create any account to send messages from `sendmail`, you can send from `pretty-much-about-anything@my-domain.com`. You might only need an account if you want to *receive* messages for that user on that server (unless you create an `alias` for that name to an existing user account), but that's not a sendmail-related question.